# How to handle failures when one of the router actors throws an exception

Tags: scala, akka

Say I have an email sender actor that is responsible for sending out emails.
I want to limit the # of actors created for sending emails, so I created a router.

```
class EmailSender extends Actor {

    val router = context.actorOf(RoundRobinRouter(4).props(EmailSender.props))

    def recieve = {
        case SendEmail(emailTo: String, ..) =>
            router ! SendEmailMessage(emailTo,.. )
        case ...
    }
}
```

I want to understand 2 things here:

1. If an email message sending fails by one of the router actors, how will EmailSender get notified and will I get the exact email that failed?

Comment: I think you forgot to ask 1 thing :)  "I want to understand 2 things here"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the email sending fails within the Routee actors, the default supervision strategy is to restart the actor.

So you should be able to hook into the `preRestart` method and see which message caused the EmailSender to fail.

```
class EmailSender extends Actor {

    def recieve = {
        case SendEmail(emailTo: String, ..) =>
            router ! SendEmailMessage(emailTo,.. )
        case ...
    }
    override def preRestart(reason: Throwable, message: Option[Any]): Unit = {
       // log the failed message. Or send it back to failedMsg processer
       if (message.isDefined) {
         failedEmailsProcessor ! message.get
       }
    }

 }
```

*Note:* I the supervision strategy is `AllForOneStrategy` then preRestart would be called for all the child actors. So it's better to have `OneForOneStrategy` here, so that preRestart is called only for the failed actor.

Comment: I would recommend to map the message instead of `.isDefined` + `message.get`

Comment: I just noticed that, I threw an exception and in the logs I could see all the actors in the router being restarted.

Answer (score 0):

In the class that contains the router you put the emails into a list pending email.

When a email has been sent out successfully to EmailSender, it sends back an message saying success and the router class will remove it if from the pending list or a failure message and the router can try one more time depending you your business logic.

Comment: If I am not using persistence, if I restart the server then those messages will be lost.  So that side of things also has to be considered.

Comment: You could use database for this.
There is some dead letter functionality that you might be able to use for the Retry / Failure message you send back